# Cannot get intellisense properties from and EF object

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor

I have a entity model which is set up with a one to many relationship.

In my DB object, I get all the related Projects to all related Categories.

In my View, I'm trying to display every category and project, however, I can't get the properties out of the Projects entity to come up in the intellisense.

What do I need to do in order for this to occur?

### Category entity

```
    namespace YeagerTechDB.Models
    {
        using System;
        using System.Collections.Generic;
        using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
        using System.Runtime.Serialization;

        [Serializable, DataContract(IsReference = true)]
        public partial class Category
        {
            public Category()
            {
                Projects = new HashSet<Project>();
            }

            [Key]
            [ScaffoldColumn(true)]
            [DataMember]
            public short CategoryID { get; set; }

            [Required]
            [StringLength(20)]
            [DataMember]
            public string CategoryDescription { get; set; }

            [DataMember]
            public virtual ICollection<Project> Projects { get; set; }
        }
    }

Project entity
--------------
namespace YeagerTechDB.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
    using System.Runtime.Serialization;
    using YeagerTechDB.Enums;

    [Serializable, DataContract(IsReference = true)]
    public partial class Project
    {
        [Key]
        [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        [Editable(false)]
        [DataMember]
        public short ProjectID { get; set; }

        [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        [Editable(true)]
        [DataMember]
        public short CustomerID { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required!")]
        [StringLength(30)]
        [Display(Name = "ProjectName")]
        [DataMember]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
        [Display(Name = "ProjectDescription")]
        [DataMember]
        public string Description { get; set; }

        [ScaffoldColumn(true)]
        [DataMember]
        public short CategoryID { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required!")]
        [DataMember]
        public CategoryTypeEnum CategoryType { get; set; }

        [ScaffoldColumn(true)]
        [DataMember]
        public short PriorityID { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required!")]
        [DataMember]
        public PriorityTypeEnum PriorityType { get; set; }

        [ScaffoldColumn(true)]
        [DataMember]
        public short StatusID { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required!")]
        [DataMember]
        public StatusTypeEnum StatusType { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
        [DataMember]
        public decimal? Quote { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
        [DataMember]
        public string Notes { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
        [DataMember]
        public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
        [DataMember]
        public DateTime? UpdatedDate { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public virtual Priority Priority { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public virtual Status Status { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public virtual ICollection<TimeTracking> TimeTrackings { get; set; }
    }
}
```

### DB functionality

```
public async Task<List<Category>> GetCategoryProjectsAsync()
{
    try
    {
        using (YeagerTech DbContext = new YeagerTech())
        {
            DbContext.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
            DbContext.Database.Connection.Open();

            var categories = await DbContext.Categories.Include("Projects").ToListAsync();

            return categories;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

### View

```
@model IEnumerable<YeagerTechDB.Models.Category>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<table class="table">
@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CategoryID)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CategoryDescription)
        </td>
        @foreach (var catProjItem in Model)
        {
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(m => catProjItem.Projects.)
            </td>
        }
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

### EDIT for View

```
@model IEnumerable<YeagerTechDB.Models.Category>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<table class="table">
@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CategoryID)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CategoryDescription)
        </td>
        @foreach (var catProjItem in item)
        {
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(m => catProjItem.)
            </td>
        }
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

Comment: The Projects object in the View, is defined by the Projects entity. So, therefore, I expected it to brining in the intellisense for those properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looping over the wrong entity in the inner loop. Instead of:

```
@foreach (var catProjItem in Model)
```

Use:

```
@foreach (var catProjItem in item.Projects)
{
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(m => catProjItem.ProjectID)
    </td>
}
```

Your `catProjItem.Projects` is an `ICollection<Project>`, so it doesn't have `Project` properties, it has `ICollection` properties.

Comment: That didn't work... I get the intellisense error "foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type YeagerTechDB.Model.Category because YeagerTechDB.Model.Category does not contain a public definition for GetEnumerator'. See edit....

Comment: CodeCaster, the update you posted doesn't work... See my edit and my intellisense why it doesn't work.

Comment: Nevermind CodeCaster... Sorry for the confusion. I didn't look at the bottom of your edit. That'll work. Than you very much.

Comment: CodeCaster, thanks so much for your solution. By explaining it to me and with the code snippet, I now understand....